# Use FROM clause when creating a table that references the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench and i am trying to create a table with a primary key constraint without using PRIMARY KEY keyword.

```
create table employee
(
    e_name varchar(20),
    e_surname varchar(20),
    depart varchar(20),
    salary int,
    check (e_name is not null and 1 = (select count(*)
                                       from employee E
                                       where e_name=E.e_name and e_surname=E.e_surname))                                    
);
```

This query causes this error: `Error Code: 1146. Table 'test.employee' doesn't exist`

Can i use FROM referring to the table that i am creating? Is it allowed in MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a primary key constraint that doesn't use the `primary key` keyword.  A primary key has three properties:

- It is unique.
- It is not `NULL`.
- There is only one per table.

It is the third that you cannot guarantee.  However, you can easily impose the first two conditions:

```
create table employee (
    e_name varchar(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    e_surname varchar(20),
    depart varchar(20),
    salary int
);
```

There is no use of a `check` constraint for this purpose.

Comment: I understand, but can I use FROM clause in that way (referring to the same table that I am creating) for other purposes?

Comment: @Angelo . . . `check` constraints only check values within a single row.  They do not have a convenient mechanism for enforcing checks over all rows in a table.